# Finding a line in a string, and grabbing information from line

Tags: c#, file

Alright, so I have a text file with some data in it, in this format:

```
Info1-Info2
Info3-Info4
Info5-Info6
```

With my program, I would like to be able to get the contents of a line, based on the first piece of information I give. So, if I give "Info3", I would like to be able to get the value "Info4" and place it into a string.

I have the text from the text file stored in a string already, so I just need to manipulate the string so that I can get the information that I want.

Sorry if I explained this in a bad way. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use an IDictionary instead.

When reading from your file put the left part (before "-") as the Dictionary Key and the right part as the Value.

Then you can just get the value by the key:

dictionary["Info3"]  will return "Info4".

Let me know if you need some actual code...

**EDIT**: Adding code

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string line;
            //initialize Dictionary

            var keyMatch = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            //opening the file
            using (TextReader re = File.OpenText("Sample.txt")) {
                //loop through lines
                while ((line = re.ReadLine()) != null) {
                    keyMatch.Add(line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf("-")), line.Substring(line.IndexOf("-") + 1));
                }
            }

            var test = keyMatch["Info5"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer.  This is the textbook example use for a dictionary object.

Comment: Oh, make sure your keys are unique. Or else, before inserting in the dictionary you should so a "Contains" check. I didn't add that to keep the example simple.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you tagged this as "regex." It sounds like you want to do a switch based on the input line (eg. Info3) and accordingly it'll match something out of the output line (eg. Info4). If you want the ENTIRE section to match (not just something in Info4), just use a dictionary like mentioned above.